# Are constant and identity only analytic functions such that $f(f(x))=f(x)$?

Tags: proof-writing, functional-equations, analytic-functions

If a function over reals is given by
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
and satisfies 
$$f(f(x))=f(x),$$
does this imply that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = c$ are only valid choices for $f(x)$?

It *seems* obvious that if can't be anything else, but I am having trouble with devising a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(f(x))=f(x)\implies f'(f(x))f'(x)=f'(x).$$

Comment: To add to this hint, if $fg=0$, $f$ is continuous *with a discrete set of zeros*, and $g$ is continuous, then $g=0$.